# How to open user-selected file (android-api-16)?

Tags: android, android-intent

When a user opens text file he is presented with "open with" dialog where he picks my application (and might choose "use by default"). From there how can I get path to the file that user selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getIntent().getData()` will return the `Uri` associated with whatever the user opened. You can then use a `ContentResolver` to get at that content as a stream.